# If cell contains 1 alpha numeric followed by four numbers then show X

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula

I’m trying to figure out the proper if statement for this. I have a cell that I input a User ID into and then have some “check boxes” to select the type of user. I want to use the if statement for the check box. So if the User ID is formatted like a1234 then an X will appear if not then it remains blank.

Comment: How have you tried to use data validation?  And what went wrong? You might also want to read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: X will appear where? And how does the check box actually relate if the validation is on the ID entered in a cell?

Comment: So let’s say B4 has an if formula checking to see if A1 equals a1234... the issue is that A1 could be b3245 or c3245 or any combination of numbers. I know I could say “a*” but some user ids are formatted like a3d2 and I don’t want those counter.

Comment: What exactly is the rule for a User ID?

Comment: Start by figuring out how to detect if a cell contains at least one letter, then show us the formula you created. Then you'll have something we can help with.

Comment: so what are the conditions when it is not X? so, must be alphanumeric followed by pure numbers only then it is X? A sample of what userId gets what output for both X and blank would be great

Comment: need a clearer logic here. Not enough info.

Comment: Let’s say user id entered in C2 is a1234, b3245, c1111 or any alpha numeric followed by 4 numbers then B2 would show “X”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming counting X only if the format is (A-z) followed by undefined length of numbers (0-9), you could use the formula below:

```
=IF(AND(OR(AND(NUMBERVALUE(CODE(LEFT(A2,1)))>=65, NUMBERVALUE(CODE(LEFT(A2,1)))<=90),AND(NUMBERVALUE(CODE(LEFT(A2,1)))>=97, NUMBERVALUE(CODE(LEFT(A2,1)))<=122)),ISNUMBER(NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-1)))),"X","")
```

[image]